# Is there a way to get user steps to the crash in production?

Tags: android, crash-reports

I use crashlytics from Fabric to get the app crash logs, but I still miss more information, like how the user got to that point that caused the crash.
Is there a way to get user steps to the crash in production?

Answer (score 1):

Ever tried Firebase Crashlytic? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/
More details in this youtube link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_mdNRZzd30

Answer (score 1):

You can add more information to Crashlytics reports manually.

**Custom logs**

```
Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);
Crashlytics.log(msg);
```

**Custom keys**

```
Crashlytics.setString(key, value);
Crashlytics.setBool(String key, boolean value);
Crashlytics.setDouble(String key, double value);
Crashlytics.setFloat(String key, float value);
Crashlytics.setInt(String key, int value);
```

See more: [Customize your Firebase Crashlytics crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports)